# What is the best leveling spec for a Champion in LotRO?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

The title says it all. I'm looking for the best leveling spec for Champions in Lord of the Rings Online. 'Best' in a MMO means a nice balance of survivability and efficiency. This should include traits, virtues, weapons (dual wield or two handed weapons)

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on your own experience. Is there anything not working for you at the moment? That way we have an idea where your own ideas need improvement. Else this question is far too broad.

Comment: Yeah, I would answer, but it's such a bit topic, I hardly know where to start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Survivability is not a virtue of the Champion class. Survivability means for a Champion to do as much as damage so the mob(s) will die before the Champion. If in a fight the odds turn against you can switch your stance to 'Ardour' or 'Glory' and use some defence skills like 'Sudden Defence', 'Blocking Blades' and/or the emergency skill 'Dire Need' (Transfers 50% Power into twice as much Morale.) with a 30 minute CD to turn around bad situations. But on the end the Champion needs to make enough damage to kill the mob before the Champion dies.

Traits:
Discipline, Determination, Valor are must haves imho, Justice and/or Loyalty are quite good because of the extra morale and i would suggest Innocence because of the melee defence rating.

Class Traits:
4 Red; 3 Yellow imho but thats a matter of taste. 'Controlled Burn' as legendary trait is a must have.

Dual Wield vs. Two Handed:
There is probable neverending discussion dual wield vs. two handed. Most Consensus is that the damage output is nearly the same. With dual wield you'll be faster and with two handed you'll have a higher burst damage.  Most Champions prefer dual wield; i prefer two handed.

Comment: Not any more, champs now have plenty of bubbles and heals.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this question can be answered. LOTRO is very flexible when it comes to builds, and the way they unlock over time makes them difficult to pinpoint. I'm going to assume you're new to the game, and this isn't your seventh character you're leveling up...

You have three sets of traits that you can draw from. One focuses on AOE damage, one focuses on single-targets, one focuses on protection. You will unlock the different traits over time by using different skills, usually the skills that they relate to. That means your actual "leveling trait choice" is going to depend a lot on what you've unlocked. (And you should be trying to finish all the trait deeds, as best you can.)

Your play style determines what traits you'll unlock first. I, personally, went with the single-target "boosts critical chance" traits first. They seem a good choice, unlock fairly easily, and work well for the moment. I enjoy doing skirmishes, so I'll probably shift towards AOE when I have more traits unlocked for it. If I have survivability issues, I'll throw in some of the tanking traits, like Braced Against Defeat. Since it only costs 11 silver to change a trait, it's hardly a concern if I want to swap them in and out.

In the meantime, you might find good (if a little dated) information here: http://www.lotroinfo.com/champion_intro

And, of course, a list of the traits and when they start to unlock from the LOTRO wiki:
http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Champion_Traits

On 2H vs Dual, the consensus seems to be, again, to go with what feels right for you. 2H seems to be better for MPvP and power management; Dual gives more consistent damage. The differences are otherwise negligible.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the answer to this.. is the question itself.   Firstly, the only way to know what the "best" leveling build is, you would have to describe what your exact desired outcome is.  There are so many routes that you can take to adjust certain aspects of your champion that most of the time it comes down to a choice of preference.   Using the term "leveling" is a bit broad.  How are you leveling?  Are you doing Raids? Skirms? Questing Solo? Questing in Fellowships?  Basically if you were to look at this from a broad spectrum (without getting into specifics) I guess I would suggest to give yourself a desired effect first.  Then (obviously) find the best gear/trait/virtues/etc that support that end result.  When deciding your Goal try to keep in mind your style of play.  If you are going to be doing a lot of skirmishes and that's your prefered method of lvling then you would more then likely invest in supporting your AoE attacks.  If you are questing solo then you would develop your traits and such to supplement your Single Target attacks, etc.  I think you get the general idea.  Also when it comes to gear there are really two ways that people seem to "gravitate" towards their desired effect.  1 - to overpower their main stats as to make up for the lack of others.  and 2- to supplement the weaker stats to make up for the lack of them.  Again, finding the "right" combination really comes down to you cracking the numbers and making personal choices.

I think if you narrowed down the question you could more then likely get a more specific answer.  Also keep in mind that you are going to get a LOT of different opinions regardless of how specific you are with your question.  Again, a lot of it boils down to personel preference.

Answer (score 0):

I have read almost anything about this matter and talked with many players in the game and the forum..

I use 2H and the damage is ery good! However it seems preety slow. So i tried to find out if dual swords could be better.. And YES. They can do the same damage and are very fast especially if you promote your agility! The only minus is that the critical hit the 2H gives to your enemies and the duals dont.

So I am looking to find the best suitable duals for my Elf Champion now that i finished the lone lands quests and before moving to unlock Northdowns i will have my duals!

Probably daggers ,found two with the biggest dps i could find. Better than any other[skirmish camp ost guruth] weapon vendor

Have fun!

Comment: Dual-Wield generally gives more DPS>

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the situation. For example, a really good glory champ can solo an elite master in the later levels. Learning to master this stance to the best of the ability allows the champion to accomplish many feats solo that would normally be practically impossible alone.
However, soloing in glory is, well, time-consuming. It takes forever to bring mobs down in glory, (in the later levels, 65 mirkwood trolls are solo-able by a good champ.) and it is simply easier to just fight in fervour. However, most champs in fervour tend to die rather quickly when they run into a bad situation

The happy medium is "Stance-dancing", or transiting from glory to fervour. Most champs don't really see the need for this stance-dancing, and don't necessarily trait blue. They tend to avoid group areas, and solo in elite free zones. I, however, can waltz into group zones with my traits without any real concern for dying because I can switch to glory. Glory is necessary to switch to because certain champion bubbles (True heroics.)are only accessible in glory stance, extra defensive, radda, radda.)
Aggressive exchange is a must have trait, because gathering aggro is important for emergency situations in groups. Being able to quickly gather aggro (or at least steal it from the healer.) if the MT gets punted off of a cliff (DD, Uru, CD, lots of cliffs in instances.) can occasionally save a group. I tend to trait 4 blue (for the health boost.) 3 red. I also have valour, justice, zeal, and loyalty, to max out health.
Weapon choice depends on the situation as well. 2-handers are great for Ettenmoors combat, or in situations where -2,000 forced blows, and finishing off an opponent quickly is more important than overall DPS (occurs a lot in group situations, so I always have a 2-hander in my inventory.
Dual-wielding is better when Damage over time is more important than burst DPS, so I use it frequently too.