# Which is the best combination of gear and traits for a DPS champ?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I am specifically interested how to combine maximum DPS output and achieve maximum morale points. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey there! I'm not going to post an answer to this since I know nothing about LOTRO, but this guide may be of interest: http://lotro.mmodb.com/guides/champions-the-ins-and-outs-5.php ...I can't make heads or tails of most of the info :<

Comment: Related? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/best-leveling-spec-for-a-champion-in-lotro/13033#13033

Comment: Im not too familiar with this game, but i assume it is a choice. For instance maximum DPS comes at the price that you cannot achieve maximum morale and other attributes

Answer (score 4):

- **Make a Man-Champion or Dwarf-Champion** 
  This will net you addition Might from the start, which increases your melee damage. Might is the opposite of Agility, which increases your ranged damage. Also, Race of Man gets a giant (~3000) [self heal](http://lorebook.lotro.com/wiki/Skill:Strength_of_Morale) at high level. They also get a [direct bonus to Morale](http://lorebook.lotro.com/wiki/Skill:Duty-bound). But now with today's 15k tanks and with your average player at 7k health, 3k isn't really that much.

  However, Dwarf-Champions also get Might bonus. They also get a vitality bonus, which may also help you if you're trying to go for a balanced build. And, at high levels, through racial traits dwarves get [Endurance of Stone](http://lorebook.lotro.com/wiki/Skill:Endurance_of_Stone), which adds 50% to Fire, Shadow, and Common migitations. This means that 1/2 of all Fire, Shadow, and Common will be asorbed you. Also at high levels, they get Dwarf-endurance, which gives a [bonus to Vitality](http://lorebook.lotro.com/wiki/Skill:Dwarf-endurance).
- **The most important stats for a build like yours are Might and Vitality** 
  Vitality will increase your Maximum Morale (health). For every point of Vitality you have, you get three points of Morale. For instance, if you have 100 vitality, you will get 300 extra morale, in addition to your base morale (which depends on class/race) and other morale bonuses. 
  Might will increase your melee damage. Edit: Vitality also adds to your common migitation, and all other migitations (however, the other migitations will not receive as much bonus from just  vitality)
- **Get an armor set when you're at a high level** 
  One of these will help: http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Comparison_of_Champion_Armour_Sets 

  Deathstorm's Armor is seemingly for Survivability. Blade of the West armor seems to be for Damage. You might want to earn both of them and then use whichever one you'll be using.

However, as said above in a comment, **you can't have the absolute maximum health and the absolute maximum DPS at the same time**. To improve DPS, try the Fervor stance. However, this will burn down your health faster. To improve survivability, try the Glory stance. However, this will increase Threat generation, decrease damage output, and increase your defense ratings. This seems to be the "Tank" stance for Champions.

I don't think I've covered everything, so tell me if there's something I should add.

Comment: Another advantage (and a quite unknown fact) to use man as race for champions is that man have a bonus to incoming heal of 5%. That helps alot while grouped and in Fervor stance.

Comment: Yes, but I just remembered that Dwarves get Dwarf-Endurance/Endurance of Stone.

Comment: Healing isn't gonna help if the Balrog is breathing fire on you.

Comment: Incoming heal increases the heal you'll recieve; so it will help if someone heals you while the Balrog breathes fire at you ;)

Comment: Migitating 75% of that damage will help more.

Comment: Not just the Balrog, but practically everything (except that ##### Frigid Squall)

Comment: Well, the Dwarf endurance is good for sure but as man you'll get a heal of 3000 whats also not bad. The point is that incoming heal is a very important stat for Champions for difficult dungeons or raids.As a Champion you should get incoming heal to the cap of ca. 4000 incoming heal; that are 20% more incoming heal reducing the malus of Ferver stance to -10%.

Comment: well, it's equal, i guess for whether you should go with Dwarf or Man. I think that Man is good for Soloing while Dwarf is good for Grouping.